# JIRA issue resolver

Tags: jira

I'm using the standard edition of JIRA and on the whole, I love it. However, it's a frequent source of irritation that JIRA doesn't seem to record who resolved an issue, just who the current assignee is, and who reported the issue.

Because the "resolver" is not recorded there's no way to find issues that I resolved, or issues that were not resolved by me (e.g. when looking for issues to test).

Is there a configuration option somewhere that "turns on" resolver tracking?

Cheers,
Don

Comment: This link may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239532/jira-resolved-by-me-query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JIRA Enhancer Plugin](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAEXT/JIRA+Enhancer+Plugin) adds a "last resolved user" custom field. If you add this to your issues and to the issue screen you can see who the last user to resolve the issue was.

I suspect it will only be searchable for issues resolved after you add the plugin.

We had exactly the same problem so introduced the rule that the tester closing an issue re-assigned the issue back to whomever had resolved it. This was very much a workaround which now that I have installed the plugin we hopefully won7t need.

Answer (score 3):

Typically the person the issue is assigned to is the one resolving the issue. Perhaps your workflow needs to be altered so that this is the case.
However, the changelog does record who performed a particular transition. This is not queryable tho.