# JIRA - Resolved by me query

Tags: jira

How to write query that will select only issues resolved by me.

I have found some old post that says its no possible, but it might have changed.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use next JQL:
*status was resolved by "username"*

Comment: `STATUS was REOPENED and PROJECT in (A, B, C) and STATUS was RESOLVED by "daniel"` works just fine... but is there a way to query something like `STATUS was FIRST RESOLVED by ...`? That's what I'd need...

Comment: Check this out I'm not sure if this is something that might be of assistance to you or not: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/How+to+Capture+the+Initial+Resolution+Date

Comment: project = prohjectname AND status was "Resolved" by username  and resolutiondate >= '2014/01/08' and its variants exists in jql now i am not sure whether they existed at the time question was asked.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```status changed to Resolved by "daniel"```? 'Changed by' works for me instead of 'was'.

Answer (score 40):

In 4.4 this seems to work:

```
status was "Resolved" by currentUser()
```

More details can be found [here](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching).

Answer (score 8):

The answer most often given is to use JQL for something like

```
status was Resolved BY currentUser()
```

While all fine and good, this will give you back all the issues that you have *ever resolved*.  That is, if you resolved issue FOO-1966 and then it got reopened and someone else resolved it again *it is still an issue that was resolved by you*.

**Here's a better way to do this** in JIRA 6 and later (including JIRA onDemand).

1. Create a custom field called "Resolver".  Make it a person field but do not add it to any forms (unless you really want to).
2. Edit your workflow and add a post function to the resolve issue transition in your workflow.  Make the action "Update custom field" and set the Resolver to %%CURRENT_USER%%.
3. Publish your workflow.

Now whenever someone resolves an issue using that workflow, the Resolver field will get set to the current user.  Now the Resolver field is semantically "last resolved by".

As an added bonus, you can use the value in the Resolver field to reassign issues back to the person who resolved them when they get reopened.  I'll leave this as an exercise to the reader.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this JQL query:

```
 "Resolved by" = currentUser()
```

(I just verified this in v4.1.2#531 on a standalone version)

There is also a plug in you can use in older versions:
https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JQLT/Home

Comment: `Resolved by` is this custom field or out-of-the-box? I ask because in mine 4.2.1#b588 there seems to be no such field (I tried both simple and advanced search)

Comment: I see thanks. `cf[10038}` - here, `cf` seems to denote [custom field](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+a+Custom+Field) indeed

Comment: I am having `JIRA (v4.1.2#531)` but this query does not work for me. Says **Field 'Resolved by' does not exist.**

Comment: @KuldeepJain Same error message with JIRA v6.3.10 when this query is run.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me on JIRA (v4.1.2#531)

However, his works:

```
"Resource" = currentUser() AND (status = Fixed OR status = Closed OR status = "No Change Required") ORDER BY updated
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WAS operator:

[JIRA - Advanced Searching](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA050/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-WAS) : "The "WAS" operator is used to find issues that currently have, or previously had, the specified value for the specified field"

Example: status WAS "Resolved" BY currentUser()

Answer (score 1):

For JIRA v6.3.4, this worked for me:

```html
"Resolved By" = currentUser()
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use this

```
status in (resolved) AND component = COMPONENT_NAME AND assignee in (currentUser()) AND resolved > -1d
```

but the new thing here `resolved > -1d` this to get the issues that are resolved me in this day

resourses: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/JIRA-4-4-search-filter-how-to-find-issues-resolved-in-last-seven/qaq-p/77326

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, search for *resolved by me* and more generally, for status changes, is not possible until at least JIRA 4.2.1 (the version I'm using now).

Search and JQL enhancements outlined in [4.3](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+4.3+Release+Notes) and [4.4](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+4.4+Release+Notes) release notes look like the move in the right direction ([WAS operator](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/__JQL+WAS+Parameters)) but I'm not holding my breath.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me. I started adding a label to all my issues to resolved_by_kishore, then in advanced search, I'm using lables=resolved_by_kishore. It's working fine.

Comment: What version of Jira are you using?

Comment: It was old version. After we migrated to new version, these was and is are working.

Answer (score 0):

project = prohjectname AND status was "Resolved" by username  and resolutiondate >= '2014/01/08'

and its variants exists in jql now
i am not sure whether they existed at the time question was asked.

i am adding this answer so that if anyone comes here can find the answer

Answer (score 0):

The values used in `Status` can vary *(e.g. Resolved, Closed, Done, ...)* so it is not reliable to use.

Instead, use `resolution`:

```
resolution changed from EMPTY by currentUser()
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `= EMPTY` seems to work for searching for empty custom fields with newer versions of Jira

Comment: Please check if I have formatted the relevant query correctly (BTW I have not downvoted the answer)