# Jira - Get all issues that moved to "Done" on iteration X

Tags: jira, agile

How can i create a filter that captures all cards that moved to "Done" during iteration X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could work, if you're looking for issues in a certain sprint with a certain status:

```
project = MYPROJECT AND status = Closed and sprint in (mysprint)
```

Note that that can also include issues that were part of multiple sprints and closed in a later one than *mysprint*.

If you're really interested in the issues that were closed in a specific period, then use something like:

```
project = MYPROJECT AND status CHANGED TO closed DURING (2016-07-01, 2016-07-15)
```

The dates are in format *YYYY-MM-DD*.

There's a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722841/jira-jql-issues-resolved-in-the-current-sprint).
And more documentation available [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-operators-reference-764478341.html#Advancedsearching-operatorsreference-CHANGEDCHANGED).