# JIRA JQL Select Items Resolved By User

Tags: jira, jql

I'm trying to write a JQL statement to return all tickets resolved from the beginning of the month and sorted by user. I've looked at [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239532/jira-resolved-by-me-query/20808974#20808974), and additionally [This Article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-capture-the-initial-resolution-date-282174905.html). I've attempted iterations from all of the examples in the first thread with no luck. The second thread involves creating a custom field. I assuming the reason the first thread's solutions aren't working is because all of the examples are from JIRA 4.* where as I am running JIRA 7.2.

```
status was Resolved BY currentUser()

"Resolved by" = currentUser()
```

Among others are not working.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you actually have a status named Resolved?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see which issues were resolved by a specific user since the start of the month, then you can use a JQL query like this:

```
status CHANGED TO resolved BY currentUser() AFTER startOfMonth()
```

or

```
status CHANGED TO resolved BY "username" AFTER startOfMonth()
```

More info about the 'changed' operator is available [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-operators-reference-764478341.html#Advancedsearching-operatorsreference-CHANGEDCHANGED).

If you want something more generic that displays results for all users, then you can leave out the 'BY ' part, but you won't be able to order the results out of the box because issues do not have a field that contains the user that resolved the issue. In your search results, you can only order by (and add a column for) an issue field.

If you do want to add a custom field to hold the user that resolved the issue, then you could use the [Script Runner add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview), write a post function script that fills in the custom field and add the post function to the "resolve" transition in your workflow. More info about this is available in the [Script Runner documentation](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/5.3.0/jira/custom-workflow-functions.html#_introduction).